# Automatic CD/DVD ripper that supports multiple drives

Tags: dvd, cd, abcde

As the title states, im looking for an automatic CD/DVD (and maybe later an BD) ripping machine. 
The PC I build is from old hardware and stuff that i had lying around.

First the specs:

- CPU: Intel Pentium Dual Core e5300
- RAM: 4GB DDR2
- Mainboard: Gigabyte GA73PVM-52H
- Drives: 2x IDE LG DVD Burners, 2x SATA DVD Readers
- HDD: Generic 320GB Sata
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I know that this system isnt powerful. But I want something where I can put 4 CD's or DVD's into and its going to rip them and then eject them afterwards.

I have found this guide:

https://pathar.tl/blog/the-ultimate-automated-ripping-machine/

but unfortunatly I couldnt get the DVD ripping part of it to work. Another problem with this guide is that I cant (or at least I dont know how to) get it to work with multiple optical drives.

If you know any guides from people that have done similar projects you would help me a lot. Im still a noob concerning linux and coding with it, so guides that are ELI5 are really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I created the Automatic Ripping Machine https://github.com/automatic-ripping-machine/automatic-ripping-machine awhile back which sounds like what you're looking for.  Usage is insert a disc, it rips, and ejects the disk for you to insert another while it transcodes asynchronously.  I'm not sure how it would fare on older hardware--I think it would run just slower.